# Consuming JSONP with Angular ngResource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, jsonp, angular-resource

I am trying to grab data from JSONP at the following endpoint: https://careers.icims.com/jobs-api

This code is in my controller and all dependencies are included:

```
var url = "https://careers.icims.com/jobs-api";

$sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);

var jobs = $resource(url,

    { callback: "JSON_CALLBACK" },
    { get: { method: "JSONP" }}
);

var result = jobs.get({ q: $scope.searchTerm });

console.log(result);
```

But I get the following error:[image]

Ive been trying to get this to work for hours. Im not married to `$resource` either. Why is it so hard to just grab some JSONP data??

Comment: Why not just use the [$http Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)? What do you gain by using the [ngResource Module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource)?

Comment: See the breaking changes to using JSONP at [AngularJS Migration Guide (V1.6 $http)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrate1.5to1.6-ng-services-$http)

Answer (score 0):

how 'bout using

> .then(...).catch(...)

like this

> jobs.get({ q: $scope.searchTerm })
>   .then(function(response){console.log('response', response);
>   }).catch(function(error){});

Comment: I tried using `then()` before. get an error that `jobs.get(...).then is not a function`

Comment: then, use 
.get(..., function(){ ... })
related to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource